# PostDoc relocation Expenses

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom, salary, fees

I have recently accepted a postdoctoral position at a reputed institute in the UK. I am an oversees applicant, who will soon be moving to the UK to take on this role. During the interview, I did not enquire about relocation expenses, assuming there would be support for that, but I have now been told that postdocs in this institute don't get a relocation support. On top of this, new regulations on the UK visa mean that I am now having to pay almost 1200 GBP just to get a visa and permission to be in the UK.

The town I am moving to is quite expensive (almost London rates) and I am now having trouble raising money for the airfare and paying initial rent and deposit, let alone having money for food and miscellaneous expenses. I am in a very tight spot and don't know how to take the next steps. This role has come after a lot of difficulty, and this situation is making it very difficult. Any advice on what I could do ?

Comment: Even if you *would* get relocation expenses, you would likely have to pay it out-of-pocket first and only get reimbursed after considerable time and bureaucracy on the university side.

Comment: From what you've said, you're currently not in a position to afford the cost of relocation. You also say that the area you're moving too is quite expensive. Are you likely to be able to afford to live there after you've relocated?

Comment: @Ian_Fin The postdoc salary is quite decent. Once I start working, I could manage the expenses and afford to live there. 

I am just unable to front the upfront setup costs. I have just come off a few months of not being paid and in addition to this, the currency conversion from what I was paid in my last job to GBP isn't really that great either! So, the savings haven't really accounted to much!

Comment: Some places offer money to people in difficult financial situations. Maybe your institute has something like that and it's applicable to your case?

Comment: @NewPostdoc taking into account rent/food/living/etc. would you still have enough money left over to pay off a loan (either from a bank or from friends/family) during the length of your contract? Not sure how easy it would be to find/get such a loan, but it would be the most obvious way to secure the money upfront.

Comment: If you live alone a postdoc salary outside London (currently between £29301 and £38183 per year) you should be able to find cheap enough accommodation to pay off £100+/month for a bridge loan, perhaps with the exception of Oxford.

Comment: Yes, I will be earning enough to payback a loan over a period of 10-12 months. Will be difficult to do it sooner than that.  The challenge at the moment is that I might be able to raise some funds from friends and family, but it will be close to 25-30% of the set up costs and not more. Even then, they might require me to repay within a short duration.  I am not sure, if a bank would give me a loan.

Comment: Is it advisable to mention my situation to my PI or HR ? Could they help in any way or would this impact me negatively?

Comment: @NewPostdoc Did you accept the position before you found out that there would be no relocation costs? How did you find this out?

Comment: @ian Unfortunately yes, I accepted it before asking. This is my first postdoc role. In the past, I know of people who were offered moving expenses and I therefore assumed there would be one. Neither the PI , not the HR offered it, I finally asked the hr and pi recently,  and they emailed back saying there wasn't one.

Comment: @NewPostdoc If you accepted the position without knowing whether there would be relocation costs then the PI and/or HR are somewhat entitled to feel a little irritated if you then reveal you're requiring relocation costs in order to begin the job. That's not a reason to withhold this information from them, but it is something you may want to factor into your decision. One thing you may need to keep in mind is that one option you have is to withdraw from the job. Of course, if you do this it's best if you don't leave it until the last minute as that may only increase the irritation

Comment: The challenge with the relocation expenses have emerged more so recently due to a few change in circumstances and changes in the visa requirements which have now meant that I am paying double.the amount that I had allocated for the visa. Not in a position to withdraw from the job, at this point.  Will figure something out. Thank you very much for your comments and advice. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: I'd consider it the norm not to be offered to pay the relocation expenses, not the other way round.

Comment: In my personal experience when coming as a postdoc to the UK, I asked whether there was any help for relocation expenses from the US to London. They covered a lot of it, including airfare for me and my spouse and a huge container in a ship with all our stuff. I think in total it was over £4k. They did not cover visas though, which were expensive. Also, I did have to pay everything upfront and had it reimbursed later after I arrived. You should definitely ask again!

Comment: I think dbluesk's experience is the exception.  Postdocs may be coming for a year or two so relocation expenses don't make a lot of sense for a university to cover. // If you were coming to the U.S., you could get a loan in a credit union in the same town or city, on the basis of the letter of employment.  Hopefully that is the case in the UK as well.  Suggest you put most of your belongings into storage for now. // Perhaps your new employer would be willing to buy your plane ticket.  Also I wonder if their int'l student office has some tricks for getting the visa cheaper.

Comment: I would like to caution people commenting, who have primarily North American experience, that things can work **very differently** in the UK, especially when academia and immigration intersect

Answer (score 4):

You have been told (by HR I assume) that postdocs can not claim their relocation expenses from the University. However, there is a chance you can claim (some) reimbursement from the School/Department or from your PI's grant. It is a bit late to negotiate this already, but it probably does not hurt to ask.

However, if the answer appears to be negative, unfortunately, there is not much to be done. Welcome to the dark side of academia.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why this point wasn't brought up yet, but have you considered the possibility of a part-time job?  The easiest as an academic would be to tutor high school or undergrad students. With your credentials there shouldn't be too many problems.

Or you could apply for jobs with very low requirements, like cashier at a grocery store, waiting staff at a restaurant, etc. Most people take up a second job when they're short on money.

You could also ask your PI of they can cover it by explaining your financial situation. But honestly, if I were you, I'd just get a part-time job to raise at least some part of the funds before asking others for help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of the relevant legal issues, but if you need a visa to come to the UK as a postdoc, then getting a part-time job might be far from trivial

Comment: @YemonChoi as I understand the OP's post, the OP hasn't even raised the funds for airfare or visa application, so I'm assuming the OP is in his country of citizenship for the time being. I'm just advising him to use that time wisely.

Comment: Sana, point taken - perhaps you could clarify that your advice applies to seeking work **before** coming to the UK. OTOH, it says near the start that the OP "will soon be moving to the UK to take on this role".

Comment: Thanks Sana. Couple of companies that I had previously spoken to, before I got this role have shown interest in offering me some consulting work. I am trying to find out figure out if I would be allowed to this part time.

Comment: @YemonChoi I am allowed 20 hours of part time work per week.

Comment: @NewPostdoc OK, but double-check on the visa. The UK is not in a particularly easy-going phase right now when it comes to such matters...

Comment: @YemonChoi nothing has changed so far regarding immigration. It might change when Brexit is triggered, but for now, if the university made an offer, it's because they can definitely sponsor him on the right visa, which is usually a Tier 2 for a postdoc. This means 20 hours of part time work per week.